# jQuery Hide is not working in function

Tags: jquery

please help me why hide is not working in function

**Html**

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
  <b>EmpName</b>  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <span class="Error" id="Span_Name">Enter Name</span>

  <b>Email</b>  <input type="text" id="txtEmail"/>
  <span class="Error" id="SpanEmail">Email</span>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var IsOk = Validation();
})
function Validation() {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var IsVailied = true;
  $('.Error').css('background-color', 'black'); //Working
  $('.Error').hide();
}
```

Comment: any error in the console?, if the script run on load?

Comment: no their is no error but  $('.Error').css('background-color', 'black');  is Working

Comment: In stylesheet '.Error' class contain any properties like: .Error { display: block !important; }?

Comment: you are calling function on form submission? Where is the form? I din't see any form here. Please share complete form code

Comment: Can you run your complete code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and share the link?

Comment: If your javascript is in file (not embedded in the page), make sure to [clear cache then refresh page](https://superuser.com/a/512833/250606) and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine. You just have to add a `submit` button **inside the form** so that `Validation()` executes. Below is the snippet:

```js
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var IsOk = Validation();
})
function Validation() {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var IsVailied = true;
  $('.Error').css('background-color', 'black'); //Working
  $('.Error').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post">
  <b>EmpName</b>  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <span class="Error" id="Span_Name">Enter Name</span>

  <b>Email</b>  <input type="text" id="txtEmail"/>
  <span class="Error" id="SpanEmail">Email</span>
<button id='button'>Submit</button>  <!-- \\ Put this inside the form-->
</form>
```

**It is working as expected. **

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected. Below is the small demo in snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function(){
   $('#form1').submit();
  });
  $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var IsOk = Validation();
  });
  Validation = function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var IsVailied = true;
    $('.Error').css('background-color', 'black'); //Working
    $('.Error').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form1'>
  <b>EmpName</b>  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <span class="Error" id="Span_Name">Enter Name</span>

  <b>Email</b>  <input type="text" id="txtEmail"/>
  <span class="Error" id="SpanEmail">Email</span>
</form>
<button id='button'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I have just change the function declaring type but that does not matter if your validation function is being called. Added a form and button for DEMO purpose and it works as expected. In short no changes to your code which depicts that your code should be working as expected.

Comment: @MDmohi  you are calling function on form submission? Where is the form? I din't see any form here. Please share complete form code